# Unable to connect to RabbitMQ in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

Below is the code used for testing the Rabbitmq connection in spark scala.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory
def getRabbitMQConnection()={
    val factory = new ConnectionFactory()
    factory.setUsername("****")
    factory.setPassword("****")
    factory.setHost("***")
     factory.setVirtualHost("5672")
    val connection = factory.newConnection()
  
}
```

When I tried to connect, I get the below error.

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=530, reply-text=NOT_ALLOWED - access to vhost '5672' refused for user '****', class-id=10, method-id=40)
```

Could someone please assist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
access to vhost '5672' refused for user '****'
```

I think you are confusing the TCP port with the Virtual host.

try with:

```
 factory.setVirtualHost("/")
```